# How to iterate over body of POST request in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I'm constructing a generic route handler for POST requests in NodeJS.

I need to iterate over the `req.params` of the POST request, without knowing beforehand what the parameters are.

I have tried the following without success:

```
console.log("checking param keys...")
Object.keys(req.param).forEach(function(key){
console.log(key +"is " + req.params(key) )
})
```

When I run this code, only the "Checking param keys..." gets printed.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: i think you mean `req.params[key]` not `req.params(key)`
Or possibly `for(var key in req.param) { ... }`

Comment: in the future when in doubt it may help todo a console.dir to give you a better view of an object, while debugging

Comment: Thanks for your ideas Mouseroot, your are right!  by simply logging req to the console and then logging those keys one by one I managed to figure out that the form keys are actually in req.body, not req.param as one might think...Edited post to include solution! Cant believe I didnt think of that earlier! =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're asking how to iterate form post from a url encoded POST request body, so it is [bodyParser()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser) middleware that did your trick.

`req.params` is an array that contains properties mapped by routing defined express app. see details from [req.params](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params), not the request body. Take the follow code for example:

```
var app = require("express")();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post("/form/:name", function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.params);
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.query);
   res.send("ok");
});
```

Then test it like this:

```
$ curl -X POST --data 'foo=bar' http://localhost:3000/form/form1?url=/abc
```

You will see the console output like this:

```
[ name: 'form1' ]
{ foo: 'bar' }
{ url: '/abc' }
```

So `req.body` is the right way to access request body, `req.query` is for read query string of all HTTP methods.